# What is the effect of the MatchCase argument of the Range.Sort method?

Tags: excel, sorting

What is the effect of the `MatchCase` argument of the [`Range.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort) method?

I tried typing a few uppercase and a few lowercase words and the `MatchCase` argument doesn't seem to affect the result.

For example, selecting the following range:

```
a
A
b
B
```

And executing any of the following lines, returns the same result:

```
Selection.Sort Key1:=Selection.Cells(1,1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, MatchCase:=False
Selection.Sort Key1:=Selection.Cells(1,1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, MatchCase:=True
```

I would expect for the latter to return this:

```
A
B
a
b
```

Comment: [Here](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/sorting.htm#order) it says it's case insensitive anyway (the list is quoted from an old Excel documentation, I have it installed locally and can confirm; it would appear it's been removed from newer documentation).

Comment: My understanding (and limited testing agrees) that  with `MatchCase:=True` the sort order is `"a" < "A" < "b"`. Your `ABab` order is what would result from setting, in a vba module `Option Compare Binary` where the sort order is based on the character ASCII value. I have not seen this documented anyplace.